# Are pulpits Scriptural requirements for preaching during Christian corporate worship?

Tags: historical-interpretation, nehemiah

The use of some sort of pulpit dates back to Old Testament times as I observed it was first mentioned in Nehemiah 8:4:

> And Ezra the scribe stood upon a pulpit of wood, which they had made
>   for the purpose. (KJV)

I observed that before Nehemiah, preachers didn't use any sort of pulpit. I also observed that the Lord Jesus did not have any need for pulpit in his days and the first-century Christian churches did not use pulpits either.

In recent times, however, we are beginning to witness the presence of a pulpit in virtually every church sanctuary. So, are pulpits Scriptural requirements for preaching during Christian corporate worship?

Answer (score 2):

The text of Neh 8:4 is much better translated to mean that Ezra stood on a high wooden platform as most modern versions have it.  That is, Ezra was elevated so people could see him in the very large crowd of many thousands.  Solomon had a similar platform built so that the crown could see and hear him at the dedication of the temple.  It was presumably demolished afterward.

Therefore, no "pulpit" or lectern was used at all (that has been recorded) in the Old Testament.

As best I can determine, no pulpit or lectern is recorded as being used in the New Testament.  In fact, sermons were sometime delivered in various places in the absence of all such formal ecclesiastical furniture.  Take the example of Paul preaching by a riverside in Acts 16:13, 14.  Paul also preached in prison while in stocks, out in the open, on the beach, on Mars Hill and many other places.

There is no scriptural requirement for preaching the Word of God using a pulpit.  In fact, Paul instructs Timothy in 2 Tim 4:2 to, "Preach the word; be prepared in season and out of season; correct, rebuke and encourage--with great patience and careful instruction."